When and how to use PrismNavigationPage (Prism MAUI)
I am migrating a Xamarin Forms app to Prism MAUI.
In the PrismAppBuilder action on startup I initialise our navigation stack like this
prism.CreateWindow( 
            "NavigationPage/HomeViewModel",
            HandleNavigationError);

My understanding is that the use of "NavigationPage" at the start of the uri is telling Prism to wrap Home in a Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NavigationPage.
When running the app in iOS I see a warning after pressing the "Back" button in the NavBar that says

NavigationPage has encountered an unhandled GoBack. Be sure to inherit
from PrismNavigationPage.

All the Views in our app are ContentPages. What or where should I be inheriting from PrismNavigationPage?
